# Laravel: why every route is executed twice?

Tags: laravel

In my laravel app, I noticed that every route is executed twice, and can't figure out why

for example:

```
Route::get('called_twice', function () {
   dump('---');
});
```

return string '---' twice

[image]

Edit:

trying to backtrace the source of the issue, I put a dump in file

> src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected function sendRequestThroughRouter($request)
{
    $this->app->instance('request', $request);

    Facade::clearResolvedInstance('request');

    $this->bootstrap();
dump('kernel');
    return (new Pipeline($this->app))
                ->send($request)
                ->through($this->app->shouldSkipMiddleware() ? [] : $this->middleware)
                ->then($this->dispatchToRouter());
}
```

and another dump in the constructor of the file

> src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php

```
    public function __construct(Container $container = null)
{
    dump('pipeline');
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

and I get this:

[image]

the Pipeline class is called many time

Laravel  6.8.0

Comment: Where it was defined?

Comment: it is defined in the routes/api.php file

Comment: Are you using WAMP by any chance

Comment: @AlecJoy no, running php artisan serve

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think $next($request) is probably called twice in a middleware. The reason is that the response is passed throught each middleware (pipes) before it is returned back.
So if $next($request) is called twice in one middleware it is normal that all pipes will be called again.

Answer (score 0):

Found mine in the master.  there was a script that was causing the page to reload in the background.

I built a little counter with admin access only and smoked it out.  Came down to one script.